# Error message from BibTeX: "Illegal, another \bibstyle command"

Tags: bibtex, achemso

BibTeX -- not BibLaTeX -- is compatible with the [`achemso`](https://ctan.org/pkg/achemso?lang=en) package.  When I run the MWE below (first I run pdfLaTeX, then I run BibTeX), BibTeX gives the following error message:

```
Running `BibTeX' on `test2' with ``bibtex "test2"''
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX)
The top-level auxiliary file: test2.aux
The style file: achemso.bst
Illegal, another \bibstyle command---line 8 of file test2.aux
 : \bibstyle
 :          {achemso}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
Database file #1: acs-test2.bib
Database file #2: test2.bib
achemso 2020-05-27 v3.13a
(There was 1 error message)

TeX Output exited abnormally with code 2 at Mon Jan 24 15:19:42
```

What does the error message mean? Why does it say I have more than one `\bibstyle` command?  How can I correct this?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[journal=jacsat,manuscript=article]{achemso}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @ARTICLE{Hirao2022,
    author = {Hirao, Yasukazu and Ihara, Keiji and Ishibashi, Yukihide and Tiu, Elisha Gabrielle and Asahi, Tsuyoshi and Kubo, Takashi},
    title = {Mechanism and Kinetics of Fluorescence Quenching of Fluorene-Endcapped Butatriene: A Microspectroscopic Study of the Discrete State Constructed in Microcrystals},
    journal = {J. Phys. Chem. C},
    year = {2022},
    volume = {126},
    pages = {1196--1203}
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\author{First A. Author}
\affiliation[University A]{Department, University A, Address A}
\author{Second B. Author}
\affiliation[University B]{Department, University B, Address B}
\author{Third C. Author}\email{thirdauthor@univc.edu}
\affiliation[University C]{Department, University C, Address C}

\title{Article Title}

\SectionNumbersOn

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract goes here.
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

\section{Methods}

\section{Results and Discussion}

Reference a paper.\cite{Hirao2022}

\section{Conclusion}

\begin{suppinfo}
  Advertisement for, and description of, Supporting Information goes here.
\end{suppinfo}

\begin{acknowledgement}
  The authors thank funding sources.
\end{acknowledgement}

\begin{tocentry}
  Graphical TOC goes here.
\end{tocentry}

% References
\bibliographystyle{achemso}
\bibliography{test2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you have two `\bibliographystyle{achemso}` probably one is in the class file and one in your document

Answer (score 1):

David Carlisle noted in the comments that I incorrectly have two `\bibliographystyle{achemso}` commands: one in my document, and one in the class.

Indeed, I realized that in [`achemso-demo.tex`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/achemso/achemso-demo.tex) (posted [here](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/achemso)), there is a comment, along with sample code, on bibliographies in `achemso` packages:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% The appropriate \bibliography command should be placed here.
%% Notice that the class file automatically sets \bibliographystyle
%% and also names the section correctly.
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\bibliography{achemso-demo}
```

So, clearly, I should use ***only*** the command `\bibliography{achemso-demo}`, where `achemso-demo.bib` is my BibTeX file (or `test2.bib` in the MWE in the original question). When I do that, pdfLaTeX and BibTeX run without error.